# Understanding how to use typedef void function with pointers as params

Tags: c++, c, pointers, typedef, function-declaration

I'm trying to understand a firmware written in C that drives a chip for ultrawideband connections.

The firmware does heavy use of `typedef` and pointers. I've understood most of the idea behind the firmware but there's a `typedef void` function I can't understand.

Basically, the firmware creates a structure to hold the device data with

```
typedef struct
{
   //some data
   dwt_cb_t    cbTxDone; // Callback for TX confirmation event
   //some other data
} dwt_local_data_t ;
```

I've understood that the structure is named **dwt_local_data_t** and contains some variables including this strange **dwt_cb_t** type.

On the .h file **dwt_cb_t** is named as

```
// Call-back type for all events    
typedef void (*dwt_cb_t)(const dwt_cb_data_t *);
```

where **dwt_cb_data_t** is another structure in the form of

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32 status;      //initial value of register as ISR is entered
    uint16 datalength;  //length of frame
    uint8  fctrl[2];    //frame control bytes
    uint8  rx_flags;    //RX frame flags, see above
} dwt_cb_data_t;
```

Now, I'm trying to understand the meaning of `typedef void (*dwt_cb_t)(const dwt_cb_data_t *);`

From what I've understood, `typedef void` is a pointer-to-function type. It defines a variable **dwt_cb_t** that points to a function receiving as an input a constant struct **dwt_cb_data_t**

I don't know if my reasoning is correct because I can't understand why there's a `*` spaced at the end of  **dwt_cb_data_t**. Does it mean that the input of the function is the pointer of the structure? In this case, why don't write `typedef void (*dwt_cb_t)(const *dwt_cb_data_t);` instead?

Comment: Because `const *dwt_cb_data_t` is not a valid declaration for a parameter? Why do you think this should be equivalent to `const dwt_cb_data_t*`?

Comment: typedefs never define variables, they define types. You're right about the meaning of parameter, but I'm confused why you think `const *dwt_cb_data_t` is legal syntax. A pointer to `T` is always written `T*` not `*T`.

Comment: @UnholySheep @john I missed out the fact that the variable type is `const dwt_cb_data_t` and not only `const`. It makes sense now to put `*` at the very end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it more clear let's assume that there is a function declared like

```
void f( int *x );
```

The type of the function is `void( int * )`.

You can introduce an alias for this function type like

```
typedef void Func( int * );
```

and declare (but not define) the function using the alias

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void Func( int * );

Func f;

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 0;
    
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    
    f( &x );

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    
    return 0;
}

void f( int *x )
{
    ++*x;
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 0
x = 1
```

Pay attention to that you could also declare the function alias the following way

```
void typedef Func( int * );
```

Now let's declare an alias for a function pointer to the function type.

You could write simply

```
typedef void Func( int * );
```

and

```
typedef Func *FuncPtr;
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void Func( int * );

Func f;

typedef Func *FuncPtr;

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 0;
    
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    
    FuncPtr fp = f;

    fp( &x );

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    
    return 0;
}

void f( int *x )
{
    ++*x;
}
```

On the other hand, you could declare an alias for a pointer to the function type without using the alias for the function type.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void Func( int * );

Func f;

typedef void ( *FuncPtr )( int * );

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 0;
    
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    
    FuncPtr fp = f;

    fp( &x );

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    
    return 0;
}

void f( int *x )
{
    ++*x;
}
```

Now compare these declarations of  aliases

```
typedef void ( *FuncPtr )( int * );
typedef void (*dwt_cb_t)(const dwt_cb_data_t *);
```

The only difference is the types of parameters. In the first declaration the type of the parameter is `int *` while in the second declaration the type of the parameter is `const dwt_cb_data_t *`.

In C++ along with typedef(s) you may use using declarations as for example

```
using dwt_cb_t = void (*)(const dwt_cb_data_t *);
```

Using the alias declaration in C++ is more flexible because you can use template alias declarations.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
using FuncPtr = void ( * )( T * );

template <typename T>
void f( T *t )
{
    ++*t;
}

int main() 
{
    FuncPtr<int>  fp1 = f;
    FuncPtr<char> fp2 = f;
    
    int x = 0;
    char c = 'A';
    
    fp1( &x );
    fp2( &c );
    
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    std::cout << "c = " << c << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 1
c = B
```

Answer (score 6):

Stop thinking in terms of `typedef void`. You are truncating the definition this way.

The symbol defined is `dwt_cb_t` and is an alias for the type `void (*)(const dwt_cb_data_t *)` which is: pointer to function taking `const dwt_cb_data_t *` parameter and returning `void`.

In C++ you would write:

```cpp
using dwt_cb_t = void (*)(const dwt_cb_data_t *);
```

which is much clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that the input of the function is the pointer of the
> structure?

Yes, it indicates that the parameter of the function is a pointer to the struct.

> In this case, why don't write
>
> ```
> typedef void (*dwt_cb_t)(const*dwt_cb_data_t);
> ```
>
> instead?

This because the pointer symbol `*` has to be placed before an identifier, and not before type of the identifier.
In this case you can see the function as this:

```
typedef void (*dwt_cb_t)(const dwt_cb_data_t *var);
```

The only thing is that `var` is omitted.

Comment: I was missing that `const dwt_cb_data_t` was the actual type and the variable was omitted; now it makes a lot more sense

Answer (score 1):

> *Now, I'm trying to understand the meaning of `typedef void (*dwt_cb_t)(const dwt_cb_data_t *);`*

```
typedef void (*dwt_cb_t)(const dwt_cb_data_t *);
```

means, define a type `dwt_cb_t` which is a pointer to a function which returns `void` and accepts one argument of type `const dwt_cb_data_t *`.

If you have a function, like

```
 void func(const dwt_cb_data_t * data); // func accepts argument type 
                                           const dwt_cb_data_t * , returns void
```

you can write

```
 dwt_cb_t f = func;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef void (*dwt_cb_t)(const dwt_cb_data_t *);
```

This just means that `dwt_cb_data_t`  is a datatype and  `dwt_cb_data_t *` is nothing more that a pointer to it.

The function prototype is simply lacking it's formal parameter name, which is fine.
A stepped down version of this would be :

```
int myFunc(int, char*);  // no formal parameter name, just its datatype
```

And then later on, in it's implementation, you would see

```
int myFunc(int var1, char* var_ptr){
//function body 
}
```

It is just easier to read without the parameter name.